# Return type for returning an object or NULL

Tags: c++

I currently have a method that returns back an object (say school). However sometimes in that method it could return NULL which is an int. What should the return type of such a method be.that I could return any of the two safely. Any suggestions ? I am open to other approaches.

Comment: Btw, return a reference and throw. Or return a pointer and you can then return `NULL`.

Comment: @H2CO3 NULL is 0, so if it's used outside of a pointer context, will be treated as an `int` (e.g. for purpose of error messages).

Comment: @Zack Or it's defined as `__null` (e. g. in the libc coming with the LLVM toolchain) or anything implementation-defined. It isn't necessarily `0`.

Comment: @H2CO3, what type will `auto n = __null;` deduce?  For GCC it's `long`. The standard requires `NULL` to be an implementation-defined null pointer constant, where "A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`."

Comment: @JonathanWakely It's `long` for clang too.

Comment: @H2CO3 C++98 4.10p1 reads "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression rvalue *of integer type* that evaluates to zero."  (emphasis mine)  So whatever implementation-defined thing `NULL` expands to, if used outside a context where it converts to a null pointer, it *must* act like some sort of integer.  (In C++11 a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` is an alternative, but I suspect from context that the OP is not using a C++11 compiler.)

Comment: @Zack Now that's exact, it must **act like** 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably return an `std::unique_ptr<school>`, if you have a C++11 compiler. If you already have C++14 stuff, then maybe `std::optional<school>` will work. If you have boost installed and you don't have `std::optional`, you may consider `boost::optional<school>`. You should not return a raw pointer, since it's not clear then, who's responsible for deleting the pointer from the function interface.

As Andy noted, it might be an option to throw an exception, if the return value cannot be successfully constructed. This makes sense, if the case doesn't occur frequently and the caller would not typically expect the function to fail.

Answer (score 9):

If the type you want to return does not have a natural "null" value, [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) seems to be what you're looking for.

However, consider whether not being able to produce a value to return is an error condition or not. If it is, rather than returning a `boost::optional` (or a null value), consider having your function always return the intended type (whatever it is) and throw an exception when a return value cannot be produced.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return `NULL`, you may consider returning pointer of school type, as opposed to direct type. This way, you can return NULL and be able to determine from caller if the return was `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a static member of class School that is an invalid school - Something like...

```
class School {
public:
    static const School invalid; 
...
};
```

Instead of returning null, you can return a reference to the invalid school and, instead of comparing to null, compare to School::invalid.

Optionally, this invalid school could be a subclass of School with methods that do something predictable - like throw and error - without risking referencing a null pointer.

A null, like any other unnamed constant, is ambiguous about the source or intent of its value e.g., 0x00FFFFFF is less informative than Color::White.